# How to move an event from one trajectory (queue) to another in 'simmer'

Tags: r

I have a simulation of grocery checkout lanes where a customer would select the shortest queue, but at some point in time a lane will free up.  How can I move a customer from the checkout lane they are in to the available lane?  Is there a function to remove an event from one lane to another?  If I had been using a "resource" to control the allocation, can I free up a resource and then assign another?

Answer (score 0):

If you set a resource as `preemptive=TRUE, queue_size_strict=TRUE`, then you can "free it up" by setting the capacity and queue size to 0. All the arrivals in there will be dropped from the resource, so you need to set up a handler via `handle_unfinished()` to collect them and move them to the new resource.